# Flutter integration test: expect method dosen't work properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I want to test Login page in Flutter integration test, expect still at Login page when enter invalid data, and move to Dashboard page  when enter valid data.

But the `expect` method doesn't run as expected, as the test pass even any unexpected condition, like here:

[image]

But when I run the same test in debug test, `expect` works, but also the test marked as passes like here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause for this issue, it was in this method `FlutterError.onError` where it just print the exceptions

```
FlutterError.onError = (details) {
log(details.exceptionAsString(), stackTrace: details.stack);};
```

I fixed it, and `expect` is working as expected now